# Does JIT inline String class methods

Tags: java, jvm, jit, inlining

Might be a silly question:
Does JIT do method inlining to original Java library methods?

e.g. If I have a function calling `String.charAt`, would JIT inline `charAt` for me (when it's called enough times), or it has to look up vtable every time calling `charAt`?

---

A bit more context:
In a hot path, I am calling a function `replaceFirstChar`:

```java
public String replaceFirstChar(String stringVal){
  if(stringVal.charAt(0) == 'z')
    return "a" + stringVal.subString(1);
  return stringVal;
}
```

There's actually a `boolean` variable `startingWithZ` available that can tell the same as `stringVal.charAt(0) == 'z'`. So another way for me to write `replaceFirstChar` would be:

```java
public String replaceFirstChar(boolean startingWithZ, String stringVal){
  if(startingWithZ)
    return "a" + stringVal.subString(1);
  return stringVal;
}
```

I'm thinking if JIT can inline `charAt(index)` to turn it into `value[index]` (with `value` being `String`'s actual value container `byte[] value`) so that when `charAt` is called it doesn't need to go look up vtalbe, etc, then the first implementation (charAt) won't be much slower than the second, or even the same.

Comment: I assume that if it's inlining any such methods, it will be inlining String's methods.  Since Java knows the contents of its standard library up front, it would be better able to inline the methods contained therein than any other.  I expect it doesn't need to make a special case for methods in its own library, but even if it did, there'd really be no excuse for it not doing so, right?

Comment: BTW, I don't find your question to be silly.  I'm curious why you are asking it though.  Is there something that would make you think that it wasn't inlining such methods?

Comment: thanks @CryptoFool I've added a  bit more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Run a test program using these options and see for yourself: `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintInlining`

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        while (true) {
            for (var k : System.getProperties().keySet()) {
                if (k instanceof String s && s.charAt(0) == '~') {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
...
@ 42   java.lang.String::charAt (25 bytes)   inline (hot)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the code @boneill. I’m wondering is the usage of ‘System.getProperties().keySet()’ in order to avoid loop unrolling?

Comment: I wanted to ensure that the compiler didn't optimize the loop away, so I added a simple "work" step. I don't know if it was actually necessary.